# how to do left operation in vba combo box user form value?

Tags: vba, excel, userform

i want to get the the first number on left from the combobox and add different values to that regarding the first number. I did below but it gives me an error.

```
set sh2 = worksheets("sheet2").Listobjects("result")
MP= Int(Left(CB1.Value))
If MP = 2 Then
    temp = worksheets("sheet1").cells(10,5)
    sh.Range(2,2).Formula= "=temp+ D2"
else 
...
```

Comment: `MP= Int(Left(CB1.Value,1))`

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

1. Left has two criteria.
2. When using a variable in a string it must be outside the quotes

So:

```
set sh2 = worksheets("sheet2").Listobjects("result")
MP = Int(Left(CB1.Value,1))
If MP = 2 Then
    temp = worksheets("sheet1").cells(10,5)
    sh.Range(2,2).Formula= "=" & temp & " + D2"
else
```

Comment: Thanks for the catch @omegastripes

Comment: I'm getting confused with these quotations, so if i want to write a vlookup instead of adding with D it could be as this:      sh.Range(2,2).Formula= "=" & temp & " + vlookup (....)" ?

Comment: @amy yes, as long as the vlookup does not refer to a variable in the sub then it is all in the quotes.